# Unable to compile rviz on ubuntu armhf

Tags: ros, rviz, armhf, librviz, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am building ROS Groovy Desktop on a Pandaboard running Ubuntu 12.04 Precise using armhf. As ROS is not currently released for armhf I have had to compile Groovy from source. I am attempting to compile RVIZ and it crashes part-way through with errors related to "undefined reference to 'vtable for Assimp::IOSystem' "

- Does anyone know how I can get past this error and get RVIZ to compile properly?

See below for the full output from running Make within the RVIZ directory:

[ 61%] Built target rviz
Linking CXX executable /home/user/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/rviz/lib/rviz/rviz
[ 92%] Built target default_plugin
[ 92%] Generating moc_image_view.cxx
Scanning dependencies of target rviz_image_view
[ 92%] Building CXX object src/image_view/CMakeFiles/rviz_image_view.dir/image_view.cpp.o
/home/user/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/rviz/lib/librviz.so: undefined reference to `vtable for Assimp::IOSystem' /home/user/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/rviz/lib/librviz.so: undefined reference to` typeinfo for Assimp::IOSystem'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [/home/user/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/rviz/lib/rviz/rviz] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/rviz/CMakeFiles/executable.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[ 92%] Building CXX object src/image_view/CMakeFiles/rviz_image_view.dir/main.cpp.o
In file included from /usr/include/qt4/QtCore/qobject.h:48:0,
from /usr/include/qt4/QtCore/qcoreapplication.h:45,
from /usr/include/qt4/QtGui/qapplication.h:45,
from /usr/include/qt4/QtGui/QApplication:1,
from /home/user/ros_catkin_ws/src/rviz/src/image_view/main.cpp:34:
/usr/include/qt4/QtCore/qstring.h:174:17: note: the mangling of ‘va_list’ has changed in GCC 4.4
[ 93%] Building CXX object src/image_view/CMakeFiles/rviz_image_view.dir/moc_image_view.cxx.o
In file included from /usr/include/qt4/QtCore/qobject.h:48:0,
from /usr/include/qt4/QtCore/qtimer.h:48,
from /usr/include/qt4/QtCore/QTimer:1,
from /home/user/ros_catkin_ws/src/rviz/src/image_view/image_view.cpp:32:
/usr/include/qt4/QtCore/qstring.h:174:17: note: the mangling of ‘va_list’ has changed in GCC 4.4
In file included from /usr/include/qt4/QtCore/qobject.h:48:0,
from /usr/include/qt4/QtGui/qwidget.h:46,
from /usr/include/qt4/QtGui/QWidget:1,
from /home/user/ros_catkin_ws/src/rviz/src/rviz/ogre_helpers/render_widget.h:32,
from /home/user/ros_catkin_ws/src/rviz/src/rviz/ogre_helpers/qt_ogre_render_window.h:6,
from /home/user/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/rviz/src/image_view/../../../../src/rviz/src/image_view/image_view.h:31,
from /home/user/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/rviz/src/image_view/moc_image_view.cxx:10:
/usr/include/qt4/QtCore/qstring.h:174:17: note: the mangling of ‘va_list’ has changed in GCC 4.4
Linking CXX executable /home/user/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/rviz/lib/rviz/image_view
/home/user/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/rviz/lib/librviz.so: undefined reference to `vtable for Assimp::IOSystem' /home/user/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/rviz/lib/librviz.so: undefined reference to` typeinfo for Assimp::IOSystem'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [/home/user/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/rviz/lib/rviz/image_view] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/image_view/CMakeFiles/rviz_image_view.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52098/unable-to-compile-rviz-on-ubuntu-armhf/) by [gpr](https://answers.ros.org/users/3956/gpr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2013-01-13

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the same issue and I solved it by patching mesh_loader.cpp by adding the next lines after the assimp include lines:

```
#  ifdef __arm__                 // fix for ARM build
#include <strings.h>
bool Assimp::IOSystem::ComparePaths(const char *p1, const char *p2) const
{
    return !::strcasecmp(p1, p2);
}
#  endif
```

This is basically the same patch as here applied for the collada_urdf package: h++ps://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/ros-sig-embedded/26XlDtZhyNs/OexZAx6BCBcJ

---

Originally posted by [evk02](https://answers.ros.org/users/11636/evk02/) with karma: 218 on 2014-02-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 10

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TSC](https://answers.ros.org/users/8171/tsc/) on 2014-06-30**:
Did the trick to Odroid running Ubuntu Linaro 12.11 and ROS Hydro ;)

**Comment by [Tanmay](https://answers.ros.org/users/18176/tanmay/) on 2015-06-19**:
Give this man a cookie.

**Comment by [rbaleksandar](https://answers.ros.org/users/14216/rbaleksandar/) on 2015-08-23**:
Spot on. As small of a change this is without it a build of rviz is a no go. :D

**Comment by [HassanNadeem](https://answers.ros.org/users/20965/hassannadeem/) on 2016-02-05**:
Following is the path to the file "/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/src/rviz/src/rviz/mesh_loader.cpp" if you are following the setups on wiki.ros.org

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

RVIZ is pointless to have on the pandaboard.  It is not powerful enough to run it and does not have the required video drivers to make it work.  Just remove the package and anything that depends on the rviz package.

---

Originally posted by [Raptor](https://answers.ros.org/users/3237/raptor/) with karma: 377 on 2013-01-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tanmay](https://answers.ros.org/users/18176/tanmay/) on 2015-06-19**:
Interestingly if you compile it, this means you can compile packages that depend on rviz, and then disable / not actually use rviz when you are running them.

**Comment by [rbaleksandar](https://answers.ros.org/users/14216/rbaleksandar/) on 2015-08-22**:
I wanted the Rqt stuff and the Rviz was just a dependency (along with VLC player?!?!). So if you want to use and develop something like the Rqt dashboard this is definitely a must. As for using Rviz on such a platform - yeap, it's like shooting yourself in the kneecap.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Indigo builds for [Trusty armhf](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/UbuntuARM) include a patched version of ASSIMP that no longer requires patches to all of the packages that depend on it.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-09-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1